# how to set the dropdown value irrespective of case

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select id="fruits">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

I want to set Orange option as selected value in the above select dropdown.

```
$("#fruits option[value='orange']").attr('selected',true);
```

Since the value case does not match the option values case(orange and Orange)

how to set the option .

Comment: Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: You dont have an option with value orange

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `value` attribute of `<option>` :

```
<select id="fruits">
    <option value="apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

and:

```
$("#fruits").val("orange");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.val("required value")` to set the dropdown
Html

```
<select id="fruits">
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
$("#fruits").val("orange");
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r7xukzt7/4/)**